# Convert Excel query to Dax measure

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, dax

Could you help me with DAX calculation for :

```
=IF(C11=0,"- ",(C21+C26)/C11)
CONDITION
```

,this is an excel calculation i want same calculation in DAX,Power BI
[as per above image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7NOb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't structured like a table in power bi. First structure your data into a normalized table format.
Which would your columns will be
Product category Amount

If you have a way to explain your logic that would help. If you write out your logic then maybe that would clarify what you need

To get the answer you want, you will need to do some filtered measures on based off of the product category once you normalize the data. I suggest adding it to power bi and giving it a shot